# Remove ability in Tinymce to insert a table into a table

Tags: plugins, tinymce

Using the standard Tinymce Table plugin it is possible to insert a table into a cell of an existing table. I want to prevent this, preferably by disabling the Table menu option when the cursor is currently within a table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.